# Problem with loading compiled c code in R x64 using dyn.load

Tags: c, r, dll

I recently went from a 32bit laptop to a 64bit desktop (both win7). I just found out that I get an error now when loading dll's using `dyn.load`. I guess this is a simple mistake and I am overlooking something.

For example, I write this simple c function (foo.c):

```
void foo( int *x) {*x = *x + 1;}
```

Then compile it in command prompt:

```
R CMD SHLIB foo.c
```

Then in 32bit R I can use it in  R:

```
> dyn.load("foo.dll")
> .C("foo",as.integer(1))
[[1]]
[1] 2
```

but in 64bit R I get:

```
> dyn.load("foo.dll")
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Sacha/Documents/R/foo.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
nd.
```

---

Edit:

For reference, R CMD can be forced in an architecture by using `--arch 64x` :

```
R --arch x64 CMD SHLIB foo.c
```

Quite clear actually, I knew I was making a rooky mistake:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you are compiling it to a 32 bit target. You need to build it on your 64 bit machine with 64 bit tools. You can't load a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit process, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. I did build this on my 64bit machine with latest Rtools installed. Maybe it is building the 32bit version anyway?

Comment: you can check this with Dependency Walker

Comment: Used it and indeed the foo.dll is for x86. So how do I force R CMD SHLIB to make the x64 dll?

Comment: You are going to need the 64 bit version of Rtools (obviously!) I actually know nothing about Rtools so I don't have anything more helpful to offer. Sorry. The Rtools website makes it sound easy to get the 64 bit tools installed though: http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/

Comment: Rtools installs both 32bit and 64bit tools. After a bit of googling on using rtools in different architectures I found how this must be done: R --arch x64 CMD SHLIB foo.c

Answer (score -1):

what i did is to compile with --arch x64 and --arch 32 once a time and manually put corresponding .dll ( with the same name ) under separate folders src-x64 and src-i386 respectively, these two folders are under the same directory where the folder src is.