# Creating R package containing C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, r, installation, packaging

My goal is to create a package in R with C++ code: So my questions is how?

I am following the tutorial http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/stuff_for_blog/AlanRPackageTutorial.pdf on creating an R package containing C++ code. The specific code Im trying to compile and package is exactly as described in the tutorial.

R CMD SHLIB seems to be working creating .dll file.
I can load in R using dyn.load() and test it on simulated data (as described in tutorial)

R CMD INSTALL is where the problem begins. I have done two things encountering two different errors supposedly related:

1) The tutorial says the NAMESPACE file is supposed to contain the code:

```
useDynLib(XDemo)
export(XDemoAutoC)
```

When it does R CMD INSTALL fail resulting in error:

> Error in inDL(x,as.logical(local), as.logical(now),...): unable to
>   load shared object 'C:/.../libs/i386/XDemo.dll': Loadlibrary failure:
>   1% is not a valid Win32-program

2) Removing the above mentioned lines in NAMESPACE file will result in installation of package. I can succesfully load it in R but when I try to use the R function that makes a .C() call to the C++ written function I another error:

```
library(newpackage)
ls(package:newpackage)
[[1]] "XDemoAutoC"
  Warning message:
 In ls(package:newpackage) :
 ‘package:newpackage’ converted to character string
 XDemoAutoC(c(1,2,3,4))
Error in .C("DemoAutoCor", OutVec = as.double(vector("numeric", OutLength)),  : 
 C symbol name "DemoAutoCor" not in load table
```

Im running version R2.15.2 on windows 64-bit and using R64 bit.

I read the following post with a similar problem: 
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Include-C-DLL-error-in-C-symbol-name-not-in-load-table-td3464021.html

Except they mention nothing about the NAMESPACE-matter.

Also I read this post:
 [Problem with loading compiled c code in R x64 using dyn.load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916853/problem-with-loading-compiled-c-code-in-r-x64-using-dyn-load)

So I am thinking: that based on the fact that I am able to use dyn.load() in Rx64 means that I have succesfully created x64 .dll. Assuming that the NAMESPACE file is supposed to be left as in the tutorial - hopefully fixing the >>not in load table<< error - this would mean I should focus on fixing problem one. This problem seems to be caused by something related to 32-bit. I have used Dependency Walker on the .dll file but I am not sure how to interpret the results [image]

I really don't have any ideas on how to fix this problem so any suggestion on what to do would be welcome?

Comment: What architecture are you compiling for?  Your question mentions both 32-bit (i386) and 64-bit (x64).

Comment: I am noob at this with no formal training in handling computers. But I reckon its both (assuming i386 and x64 are instances of architectures). Because the created package holds both folder i386 and x64 and I can also load the created library in R32 and find the function in the package. But again using the function I get >>not in loadtable<< error.

Comment: Does `R CMD INSTALL` use R32 or R64?  Maybe you have to run that command twice, once for each.  Are you using Visual C++ to create the module?  Run `dumpbin /headers` on the DLLs to see what architecture they really are.

Comment: No I am not using Visual C++. I originally had Codeblocks installed but had to deinstall because the compiler I installed along with codeblocks conflicted with the cygwin used by Rcmd. I do not know what the connection is between Rcmd, R32 and R64 - in my installation I have Rcmd as one program, R32 (executed in cmd-mode) R64 in cmd-mode, and then I have Rgui 32 and 64. However I don't know whether cmd calls R32 and R64. Can I do dumpbin/headers in Codeblock(still have it on my other comp.)?

Comment: In cygwin, use `objdump -f XDemo.DLL`  And make sure the file in the `i386` directory actually is that architecture, and likewise for `x64`.

Comment: I do not have cygwin installed. I have downloaded and installed something referred to as Rtools containing among other things  a subset of the Cygwin tools. And installing Cygwin could create incompatibility problems since the R implementation is (so I read) very sensitive about particular version of the subsets of cygwin tools. But I get your point and I will find a way to test for architecture - although not tonight - I will install Visual C++ on another computer and test files there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong. Two quick suggestions:

1. Read the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual written to explain just this: *writing R extensions* including those with compiled code
2. Have a look at [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) which makes R and C++ extensions, including package building *so much easier*. Or so we think.  Writing a package is as easy as calling `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.  The documentation in 1) still help.

That said, if `R CMD INSTALL` fails you may have some mixup in your `$PATH`. Never ever mix MinGW and Cygwin. Make sure no Cygwin DLLs are found when you build or call R.  Path order matters *greatly*. See the manual for details.

Comment: I have tried several pathspecifications all specified in accordance with requirements as given in Appendix D of [R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html). Also I have succesfully installed the >>mypackage<< described in [Writing a package that uses
Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-package.pdf).

Comment: however I agree with your second point and will therefore in the future spend my time on learning the Rcpp-package.