# Trying to load a compiled C code in R using dyn.load(). Got an error message

Tags: c, r

I compiled a C code in the Terminal on a Mac (Mountain Lion). Trying to load it using dyn.load on a Windows 7 PC, I got this message:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Iris/Desktop/mcmc.so':
 LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

The Windows 7 is 64 bit, and the R on it is also 64 bit. I had no problem loading the C code on another MAC. I wonder what went wrong with my code. Thanks.

EDIT:

I tried a solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916853/problem-with-loading-compiled-c-code-in-r-x64-using-dyn-load), but it did not work.

Comment: Is that supposed to work?  I imagine that you need to compile it on Windows.

Comment: Yes. I have no issue loading and running it on my own computer and on another Mac.

Comment: I mean, loading a Mac shared object on Windows.

Comment: Oops. I thought that as long as it's compiled, it should work across platforms. Pardon my ignorance :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mac will compile C code to Mach-O (Mach Object) format
[Mach-O - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O)
This should work fine across the Mac platform. This is why it worked on another Mac.

Windows uses PE (Portable Executable) format
[WinPE - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)

The formats are not compatible, that's why LoadLibrary is complaining about not being a valid Win32 application - because it is not.

Recompile the C code on Windows and it should work.

Comment: Is there anyway to compile the code that can be used on different platforms? - given that I don't always know OS people use.

Comment: I have only compiled binaries for the platforms and offer the user the ability to choose which one to download. I'm not familiar with the package @DWin mentioned. Just as a case in point Oracle offers several  binary packages here: http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Comment: I wasn't "mentioning a package". I was suggesting that @Alex _build_ a cross-platform package. CRAN offers thousands of cross-platform packages (many of then have binary code) here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/